# spring bean xml configuration: map fails with autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a situation where adding the `@Autowired` annotation gives me the following error:

```
Field myMap in my.package.MyClassA required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

However, if I remove the annotation it works normally and the map is initialized. Here is how my code looks like:

**MyClassA.java**

```
public class MyClassA {
    private static int maxRetry;

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, String> myMap;

    /* Setters and Getters */
}
```

**MyClassB.java**

```
public class MyClassB {
    @Autowired
    private MyClassA myClassA;

    /* Do something with myClassA */
}
```

**bean-config.xml**

```
<bean id="myMapBean" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="R01" value="A" />
            <entry key="R02" value="B" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="myClassA" class="my.package.MyClassA">
    <property name="maxRetry">
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
    <property name="myMap" ref="myMapBean" />
</bean>
```

I have tried using the `util:map` but I get the exact same result.

Another solution I tried was setting the map as a static field (like some other fields in the class) and take out the annotation since I have read that `@Autowired` doesn't work with static fields, but if I don't autowire `private MyClassA myClassA` the static fields don't initialize with the value set in the xml. Tried using `@Component` on `MyClassA` but that doesn't fix the issue either.

Am I doing something wrong or am I using `@Autowired` incorrectly and what would be the best way to fix this? I used another project I have at hand that also uses this mapping structure and the annotation works without flaws on that project.

Comment: See the section on **Arrays, collections, and maps** in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using annotation style

`@Resource(name = "<name of map>")` to inject map instead of `@Autowired`.